# Simple spray example

Tags: python, scala, spray

I have a python client and spray(scala) REST server...

I am very new to both REST and scala (and spray)...
But basically, here is what I want to do..

I want to send a json request to the following url

```
http://localhost:8080/foo
```

This json request happens from python client..
and the scala server returns

```
"OK got the parameters {params}"
```

as response.

How do i do this or is there any example which demonstrates this?
Thanks

Thats

Comment: https://github.com/spray/spray/tree/release/1.3/examples  There is a sample dir inside spray source code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will do it. Just note that I have not set up a server (Spray Can), just a test of the routes.

```scala
import spray.routing.Directives._
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, FunSpec}
import spray.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest


object RestRoute {
  // Manifest the route as /api/v1_0/user/<intval>
  lazy val route = pathPrefix("api" / "v1_0" ) {
    get {
      path("user" / IntNumber ) { userNo => complete(s"user $userNo") }
    }
  }
}

class Test extends FunSpec with ScalatestRouteTest with Matchers {
  describe("Our routes should") {
    it("get a user value") {
      Get("/api/v1_0/user/233") ~> RestRoute.route ~> check {
        responseAs[String] should equal("user 233")
      }
    }
  }
}
```